# NumLock turns off after GRUB

Tags: grub2, numlock

In the BIOS settings, NumLock is turned on. The NumLock will continue to turn on but after you choose your OS with GRUB it will turn off automatically. The NumLock is still on while on GRUB screen though. Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can find help on how to enable Numlock in various different ways during a system startup [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock).

Comment: I tried all of them and it didn't work The problem occurs for both Ubuntu and Windows (whenever I boot those OS). Something must be wrong with GRUB maybe?